# String.getBytes() returns different values for multiple execution?

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String name = "i love my country";
        byte[] sigToVerify = name.getBytes();
        System.out.println("file data:" + sigToVerify);
        String name1 = "data";
        byte[] sigToVerify1 = name1.getBytes();
        System.out.println("file data1:" + sigToVerify1);

    }
}
```

I am trying to execute the above program but `getBytes()` gives me different values for the same `String`. Is there any way to get the same byte while executing multiple times for a given string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
System.out.println("file data:" + sigToVerify);
```

Here you are not printing the value of a `String`. As owlstead pointed out correctly in the comments, the [Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method will be invoked on the byte array `sigToVerify`. Leading to an output of this format:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

If you want to print each element in the array you have to loop through it.

```
byte[] bytes = "i love my country".getBytes();
for(byte b : bytes) {
    System.out.println("byte = " + b);
}
```

Or even simpler, use the [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte[])) method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

Comment: "The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the **unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object**."

Comment: @owlstead Wow.. sounds reasonable. Can you provide the link of that quote, that I can put it in the answer?

Comment: For sure, it's [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) - if you move it into your answer make sure you @owlstead me (I'll remove the downvote and turn it into an upvote, the rest of the answer seems sound)

Comment: You're welcome, live and learn. You should've seen my last error on crypto.stackexchange :)

Answer (score 1):

try printing out the contents of the byte array instead of the toString() result of the variable

```
for(byte b : sigToVerify)
    System.out.print(b +"\t");
```

if the bytes getting printed are the same, then you're good to go.